# Can every number be represented as a sum of different reciprocal numbers?

Tags: summation, binary, harmonic-numbers

Can every rational number be represented as a finite sum of reciprocal numbers? You are only allowed to use each reciprocal number one time per expression (So for example 3/2 cannot be 1/2+1/2+1/2).

You could then express these numbers in a kind of "binary-reciprocal" where a 1 in the nth place from the right denotes adding 1/n. E.g 17/10 could be 10011 as it is 1+1/2+1/5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling "Egyptian fractions" should turn out to be quite fruitful for you.

Comment: Clearly irrational numbers cannot be written as a sum of fractions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I cleared that up. Cleary I meant rationals.

Comment: The thing about Egyptian fractions is that they may not be distinct and if I have a number like 100 I must not use more than a single 1. Meaning that it is not obvious to me that Egyptian fractions always work.

Comment: I moved that "rational" clarification to the beginning of the Question.  Rollback the edit, mtheorylord, if I unintentionally changed your meaning.

Comment: No that's fine Thanks.

Comment: They are not harmonic numbers, just different reciprocal numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and there is a simple algorithm to achieve this. First, we subtract successive reciprocal numbers $(1/1,\ 1/2,\ 1/3,\ \ldots)$ until the remainder is less than the next reciprocal number. This is always possible because the harmonic series is divergent.

If the remainder is zero then we are done, so let us assume that
$$0 < \frac{a}{b} < 1.$$
There exists a unique positive integer $m$, greater than any of the preceding denominators, so that
$$\frac{1}{m} \le \frac{a}{b} < \frac{1}{m-1}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{1}{m} = \frac{am-b}{bm} \ge 0.$$

But
$$\frac{a}{b} < \frac{1}{m-1} \implies am-a < b \implies am-b < a,$$
so the numerator has decreased.

If the process is repeated, then the remainder will eventually be zero, since the numerators cannot decrease forever. Therefore, every positive rational number can be represented as a sum of distinct reciprocal numbers.

**Example:** To write 11/4 as a sum of distinct unit fractions, we subtract as many successive unit fractions as possible, starting with 1.

$$\frac{11}{4} - \frac11 - \frac12 - \frac13 - \frac14 - \frac15 - \frac16 - \frac17 - \frac18 = \frac9{280}.$$

The remainder lies between $\frac1{32}$ and $\frac1{31}$, so we subtract $\frac1{32}$.

$$\frac{9}{280} - \frac{1}{32} = \frac{1}{1120}.$$

Since the result is a unit fraction, we are done.
$$\frac{11}4 = \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 + \frac16 + \frac17 + \frac18 + \frac1{32} + \frac1{1120}.$$
Thanks to Barry Cipra for pointing out an error in a previous version of this post.

Comment: I don't see how you are guaranteed there'll be an $m$ available after you've gotten the number down to less than $1$.  For example, suppose you start at $11/4$.  Then ${a\over b}={11\over4}-1-{1\over2}-{1\over3}={11\over12}$.  You've already used ${1\over 2}$, but that's the unique reciprocal sandwich for ${1\over m}\le{11\over12}\lt{1\over m-1}$.

Comment: You are correct. I believe that it works if we subtract successive reciprocals as long as we can until the difference is less than the next reciprocal.

Answer (score 5):

Every positive number is a subseries of the harmonic series (maybe infinite). You do the following: if $x$ is your number - add numbers till the next step is over $x$, Then don't add the following till adding again will give you something less or equal. Proceed in this manner.

For positive rationals there is a method to achive them in a finite manner - using the following replacement $1/k+1/k=1/k+1/(k+1)+1/k(k+1)$ - Botts, Truman (1967), "A chain reaction process in number theory", Mathematics Magazine, 40 (2): 55–65

Comment: But can you prove this process isn't infinite?

Comment: It can be infinite... I wrote it in the brackets

Comment: But I asked for a finite representation. Cleary if its infinite you can use a variant of Riemann's Rearrangement like you did.

Comment: You can manipulate my solution in a way that will work in a finite manner for rationals

Comment: How does one do that? Add that in your answer please.

Comment: OK it is clear that if you can get every natural number you can get every positive rational - just divide the solution with the denominator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45194/discussion-between-mtheorylord-and-michael-chapman).

Comment: Your edit is great, though more details would be nice. For instance, it is not immediately obvious to me that the identity giving only has to be applied a finite number of times when adding $x+y$.

Comment: In fact, if you are trying to get a positive rational the process described in the first paragraph terminates and gives you a finite expression. To see this look at the sequence of differences between your target number and the partial sums, and think about what happens to the numerator at each step.

Comment: @Nate I don't see why it is true. The denominator can get very big

Comment: Sure the denominators can get big, but the numerators start shrinking. See Dave Radcliffe's answer for a proof.