# Can every positive rational number be written as the finite sum of distinct reciprocal primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, rational-numbers

Inspiration for this question: [Can every number be represented as a sum of different reciprocal numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921652/can-every-number-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-different-reciprocal-numbers)

My question: Can every positive rational number $\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$ be written as the finite sum of distinct (i.e. all different) reciprocal primes:

$$\frac{m}{n} = \sum_k \frac{1}{k},\quad k \text{ is a prime number } ?$$

Comment: Well, how would you write $\frac 14$?  Note that, if $p$ is one of your primes, then $p$ divides the denominator of $\sum \frac 1k$.

Comment: I gave the reason.  If $p$ were one of your primes we'd need to have $p\,|\,4$, hence $p=2$.

Comment: To elaborate:  if $\{p_i\}$ is a collection of distinct primes then the denominator of $\sum \frac 1{p_i}$ (in least terms) is $\prod p_i$.  Indeed, if $p$ is one of the $p_i$ then every term in the numerator is divisible by $p$, except for one.

Comment: Ok - so $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ cannot be equal to a rational number whose denominator is even. But can the denominator of the sum be odd?

Comment: The principle I gave is very general.  $\frac 1{p^2}$ is unrepresentable for any $p$.  Similarly $\frac 2p$ is unrepresentable for any odd $p$.  And so on.  Indeed, by principle shows you exactly which fractions are representable (not that the classification is terribly enlightening).  there is exactly one representable rational for each set of distinct primes.

Comment: Note that your claim is false, by the way.  $\frac 12+\frac 13=\frac 56$ is representable and $6$ is even.  All you need is for $2\in \{p_i\}$.

Comment: I think this is one of those questions which is obvious to a lot of people, but which I need time to absorb, as I'm making lots of basic errors. Will return to this tomorrow with fresh eyes I think.

Comment: When you return to it:  as far as your original question goes, note that you don't actually need to show that the denominator of $\sum \frac 1{p_i}$ is $\prod p_i$ (though it is not hard to show that).  It is entirely clear that the denominator is at least a divisor of that, hence any representable fraction in least terms has a square free denominator.  (to be sure, that condition is necessary for representablility, but it is not sufficient.)

Comment: The denominator of the sum of reciprocals of distinct primes is the product of those primes, so the only possible sums are non-integers with square free denominators. However, given a square free denominator, we know the primes by factoring it, so for every square free denominator there is only one possible numerator. This lets us check whether a/b is the sum of reciprocals of primes quite efficiently, especially if it isn’t.

Comment: So there are less than k numbers m/n with n <= k that are such a sum.